# AgentContext not found/null

Tags: node.js, lotus-domino, hcl, domino-appdev-pack

I want to run a Java agent from node.js via the proton interface. Sadly I can't get the Agent Context to work

Node.js Code

```
async function callEvalAgent(query) {
  const agent = await db.useAgent({ name: "search" });
  console.log("got the agent");

  const requestDocUNID = await db.createDocument({
      document: {
        Form: "searchRequest",
        query
      }
  });
  console.log("queryDoc created");
  console.log(requestDocUNID);

  await agent.run({
    selection: { search: { query: "Form = 'document'" } },
    context: { unid: requestDocUNID }
  });

  ...
}
```

Output:

```
got the agent
queryDoc created
B72CA8819EDA0691C1258592003BFBE5

...
```

Agent Code

```
public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {

      try {
          Session session = getSession();
          AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
          Document requestDoc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();
          String query = requestDoc.getItemValueString("query");
          
         ...

      } catch(Exception e) {
          System.out.println("bla");
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

When running the code I get a `NullPointerException` at

```
String query = requestDoc.getItemValueString("query");
```

on the Domino Server due to the agentContext being null. If I check on it afterwards by hand the document with the given UNID is present in my view.

What did I do wrong? Used the same approach as in the HCL Example [here](https://doc.cwpcollaboration.com/appdevpack/docs/en/domino-db-reference.html#run)

Comment: I don't see where query is defined in your Node.js code.
Can you include that as well?

Comment: the node.js code is working fine, problem occures in the Java code. query is given as a param to the function, so can be anything. updated the Code above

Comment: It looks like the query var isn't defined, and if you're not adding any value to the document, there won't be anything to read in the agent. I just wanted to make sure that it was defined.

Comment: Assuming that's all working fine, I'm going to go check on the java apis for context doc and check our tests.

Comment: Thanks! doublechecked a document in the database just to make sure. Creation was successfull, item "query" with valid query as content is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation should be more clear.

The documentation should say that the optional document that is provided to the Agent is available to the agent using the `ParameterDocID`.

In a Java agent do something like this:

```
    final Session session = getSession();
    final Database db = session.getCurrentDatabase();
    final AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
    final Agent agent = agentContext.getCurrentAgent();
    final String noteid = agent.getParameterDocID();
    final Document context = db.getDocumentByID(noteid);
```

In a LotusScript agent do something like this:

```
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim agent As NotesAgent
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim context As NotesDocument

    Set agent = session.CurrentAgent
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase

    Set context = db.GetDocumentByID(agent.ParameterDocID)
```